# Docker swarm doesnt save volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose

```
   version: "3.7"
   sonarqube:
        image: sonarqube:8.2-community
        depends_on:
          - db
        ports:
          - '9000:9000'
        environment:
          SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
          SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
          SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
          SONAR_WEB_PORT: 9000
          SONAR_EXCLUSIONS: java
        volumes:
          - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
          - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
          - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
          - sonarqube_temp:/opt/sonarqube/temp
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: sonar
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
        volumes:
          - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
          # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
          - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      sonarqube_data:
      sonarqube_extensions:
      sonarqube_logs:
      sonarqube_temp:
      postgresql:
      postgresql_data:
```

When i do the following command: **docker-compose up**
and then make a project in sonarqube, and then proceed to do **docker-compose down**,
and then **docker-compose up** again. it all saves.

However when i try to create a swarm with the following commands it does not save.

**docker swarm init**

**docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test-stack**

and then put it all down: **docker swarm leave -f**

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command : `docker swarm leave -f` is the opposite for `docker swarm init` not for `docker stack deploy`.
Try : `docker stack rm test-stack`
By using : `docker swarm leave -f`, you shutdown the Swarm mode, this could explain why the volumes are destroyed.